# Set visibility of textview and recycleview by check the cursor empty or not

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add message say that there is no data and recycleview which get data from cursor is empty 
I tried many solution but nothing work

this is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int INVENTORY_LOADER_ID = 0;

    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    TextView emptyList;

    Cursor inventoryData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.inventories);
        emptyList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_list);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, this, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(INVENTORY_LOADER_ID, null, this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(INVENTORY_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {

        return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(this) {

            Cursor inventoryData = null;

            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                if (inventoryData != null) {

                    emptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    deliverResult(inventoryData);
                } else  {
                    forceLoad();

                }
        }

            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {

                try {
                    return getContentResolver().query(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ID);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to asynchronously load data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public void deliverResult(Cursor data) {
                inventoryData = data;

                super.deliverResult(data);
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

I tried this in oncreate method:

```
mRecyclerView.setEmptyView(emptyList);
```

but it's seems doesn't work with recycleview so I tried:

```
if (inventoryData.isEmpty()) {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

but I got can't resolve isEmpty() method

and I tried in onStartLoading() of loader this code:

```
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (inventoryData != null) {

        emptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        deliverResult(inventoryData);
    } else {
        forceLoad();

    }
}
```

the emptylist textview is gone but it is gone in all statements when the recycleview empty and not empty

I tried this in else of above code:

```
emptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but doesn't work

also I tried this:

```
if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
    emptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    emptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

in oncreate method but the app crushed

Comment: How is this possible to set the Cursor as adapter to RecyclerView  ? **mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);** .

Comment: ` private CursorAdapter mAdapter; ` it's just name of adapter is CursorAdapter class but it's not Cursor @R7G

Comment: then try to check check the item count at onLoadFinished method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check if a cursor is "valid" or not is

```
((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0))
```

Comment: where should I check the cursor in oncreate method ? @Bruno

Comment: I think in the `deliverResult()`method